# MongoDb Search Accented Characters

Tags: php, mongodb

My site has a basic search that works good except that MongoDB treats Équinoxe and Equinoxe as two separate things, so when I search for Équinoxe it will not find Equinoxe.

Is there a way to make MongoDB think of them as the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB currently doesn't implement the Unicode locale-search algorithms, so it is up to you to come up with a way for this and create a "search friendly" extra field. I would suggest you look at the following things:

- http://pecl.php.net/translit (to get rid of accents)
- http://pecl.php.net/package/stem (for stemming, ie: stemming -> stem, walks -> walks)